# Formatting: Double hanging indent of an entire paragraph

Tags: formatting, indentation, theorems, paragraphs, definition

How would I format the following in LaTeX:

[image: Word Format]

My current LaTeX code provides this:

[image: Latex Format]

(Forgetting the Bolded text for now)

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent
%This is used throughout the rest of my paper to create a new paragraph by pressing 'enter' and indenting every paragraph%

\begin{document}

\section{Standards}

\textbf{ASTM:}

D9-12: Standard Terminology Relating to Wood and Wood-Based Products

D198-15: Standard Test Methods of Static Tests of Lumber in Structural Sizes


D1101-97a: Standard Test Methods for Integrity of Adhesive Joints in Structural Laminated Wood Products for Exterior Use 


D2559-12a: Standard Specification for Adhesives for Bonded  Structural Wood Products for Use Under Exterior Exposure Conditions

D3737-18: Standard Practice for Establishing Allowable Properties for Structural Glued Laminated Timber (Glulam)

D4688-14: Standard Test Method for Evaluating Structural Adhesives for Finger Jointing Lumber

D6874-12: Standard Test Methods for Nondestructive Evaluation of Wood-Based Flexural Members Using Transverse Vibration

D7199-07: Standard Practice for Establishing Characteristic Values for Reinforced Glued Laminated Timber (Glulam) Beams Using Mechanics-Based Models

\end{docuemnt}
```

I have tried the `\usepackage{changepage}` with the code `\begin{adjustment}{2cm}{}` at the beginning of each line as well as at the beginning of the section.

I have tried `\usepackage{tabto}` - although i may using the `\tab` in the wrong places

I have tried the `\quad`

I have probably tried other alternatives, i just cant remember all the options i have tried.

Maybe creating a list would work? or making each entry a `theorem` with the `amsthm` Just wondering if there is a faster way as i have a few of these to do?

Comment: I'd suggest using a (customized) `description` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a customized `description`list:

[image]

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent
%This is used throughout the rest of my paper to create a new paragraph by pressing 'enter' and indenting every paragraph%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=2\parindent,labelindent=\parindent}
\begin{document}

\section{Standards}

\textbf{ASTM:}

\begin{description}
\item[D9-12:] Standard Terminology Relating to Wood and Wood-Based Products

\item[D198-15:] Standard Test Methods of Static Tests of Lumber in Structural Sizes

\item[D1101-97a:] Standard Test Methods for Integrity of Adhesive Joints in Structural Laminated Wood Products for Exterior Use 

\item[D2559-12a:] Standard Specification for Adhesives for Bonded  Structural Wood Products for Use Under Exterior Exposure Conditions

\item[D3737-18:] Standard Practice for Establishing Allowable Properties for Structural Glued Laminated Timber (Glulam)

\item[D4688-14:] Standard Test Method for Evaluating Structural Adhesives for Finger Jointing Lumber

\item[D6874-12:] Standard Test Methods for Nondestructive Evaluation of Wood-Based Flexural Members Using Transverse Vibration

\item[D7199-07:] Standard Practice for Establishing Characteristic Values for Reinforced Glued Laminated Timber (Glulam) Beams Using Mechanics-Based Models
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, except for some reason i'm not getting the indentation of the each `item` like you are.    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMnNh.png

Comment: Did you use the exact same code as in my answer or did you incorporate it into your actual document?

Comment: I incorporated it into my actual document, but i have found the fix. My ASTM was already indented to `\parindent` so: from your original code `\setlist[description]{leftmargin=3.5\parindent,labelindent=\parindent}` i changed it to  `\setlist[description]{leftmargin=3.5\parindent,labelindent=1.5cm}`

Comment: Alternatively, i could have added `\noindent` infront of the ASTM. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A solution combining use of a description environment with the `adjustwidth` and `linegoal` packages:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax} \usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox, linegoal}
%This is used throughout the rest of my paper to create a new paragraph by pressing 'enter' and indenting every paragraph%
\begin{document}

\section{Standards}

\textbf{ASTM:}
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\dimexpr\parindent + \labelsep}
\begin{description}[labelindent=1.5em]
\item[D9-12:]\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Standard Terminology Relating to Wood and Wood-Based Products}

\item[D198-15:] \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Standard Test Methods of Static Tests of Lumber in Structural Sizes}


\item[D1101-97a:]\parbox[t]{\linegoal }{Standard Test Methods for Integrity of Adhesive Joints in Structural
Laminated Wood Products for Exterior Use}


\item[D2559-12a:] \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Standard Specification for Adhesives for Bonded Structural Wood
Products for Use Under Exterior Exposure Conditions}

\item[D3737-18:] \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Standard Practice for Establishing Allowable Properties for Structural
Glued Laminated Timber (Glulam)}

\item[D4688-14:] \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Standard Test Method for Evaluating Structural Adhesives for Finger
Jointing Lumber}

\item[D6874-12:] \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Standard Test Methods for Nondestructive Evaluation of Wood-Based
Flexural Members Using Transverse Vibration}\null

\item[D7199-07:]\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Standard Practice for Establishing Characteristic Values for Reinforced
Glued Laminated Timber (Glulam) Beams Using Mechanics-Based Models}
\end{description}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]